# How to Remove Pipe character from a data filed in a pipe delimited file

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix

Experts, i have a simple pipe delimited file from source system which has a free flow text field and for one of the records, i see that "|" character is coming in as part of data. This is breaking my file unevenly and not getting parsed in to correct number of fields. I want to replace the "|" in the data field with a "#".

Record coming in from source system. There are total 9 fields in the file.

```
OutboundManualCall|H|RTYEHLA HTREDFST|Free"flow|Text|20191029|X|X|X|3456
```

If you Notice the 4th field - Free"flow|Text , this is complete value from source which has a pipe in it.
i want to change it to- Free"flow#Text and then read the file with a pipe delimiter.

Desired Outcome-

```
OutboundManualCall|H|RTYEHLA HTREDFST|Free"flow#Text|20191029|X|X|X|3456
```

I tried few awk/sed combinations, but didn't get the desired output.

Thanks

Comment: `out = in.split("flow|")[0] + "flow#" + in.split("flow|")[1]` would do the job. Can be improved

Comment: How are you to be expected to parse unbalanced quotes? Fix the upstream data producer to produce valid CSV

Comment: Hi Glenn, i agree it should a balanced quotes, however our hands are tied. Source system change seems to be out of option here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know there are 9 fields, and the 4th is a problem: take the first 3 fields and the last 5 fields and whatever is left over is the 4th field.

You did tag [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), so here's some bash: I'm sure the python equivalent is close:

```sh
line='OutboundManualCall|H|RTYEHLA HTREDFST|Free"flow|Text|20191029|X|X|X|3456'
IFS='|'

read -ra fields <<<"$line"
first3=( "${fields[@]:0:3}" )
last5=( "${fields[@]: -5}" )

tmp=${line#"${first3[*]}$IFS"}   # remove the first 3 joined with pipe
field4=${tmp%"$IFS${last5[*]}"}  # remove the last 5 joined with pipe
data=( "${first3[@]}" "$field4" "${last5[@]}" )

newline="${first3[*]}$IFS${field4//$IFS/#}$IFS${last5[*]}"
# .......^^^^^^^^^^^^....^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^....^^^^^^^^^^^
printf "%s\n" "$line" "$newline"
```

```
OutboundManualCall|H|RTYEHLA HTREDFST|Free"flow|Text|20191029|X|X|X|3456
OutboundManualCall|H|RTYEHLA HTREDFST|Free"flow#Text|20191029|X|X|X|3456
```

---

with awk, it's simpler: If there are 10 fields, join fields 4 and 5, and shift the rest down one.

```sh
echo "$line" | awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" }
    NF == 10 {
        $4 = $4 "#" $5
        for (i=5; i<NF; i++)
            $i = $(i+1)
        NF--
    }
    1
'
```

```
OutboundManualCall|H|RTYEHLA HTREDFST|Free"flow#Text|20191029|X|X|X|3456
```

Comment: I think the shell solution will be more robust if there happens to be more than one pipe in the troublesome 4th field.

Comment: Hi Glenn, thanks a lot. This is helpful. How will it be handled if the delimiter is in the last field of the file. If i do last=( "${fields[@]: -1}" ) , it is going to break the record right at delimiter instead of getting full value of the field as we have IFS set to "|" . Example- 'OutboundManualCall|H|RTYEHLA HTREDFST|3456|20191029|X|X|X|Free"flow|Text'        .Here the delimiter is in the last field (9th field)

Comment: @Sidd you have to have better control over how data gets into the file. This is the kind of thing the CSV format was designed for but you're not using it. If you have no control over this file, then complain to someone who does because right now, you're screwed.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged your question with Python so I assume a Python-based answer is acceptable.
I assume not all records in your file have the additional "|" in it, but only some records have the "|" in the free text column.
For a more realistic example, I create an input with some correct records and some erroneous records.

I use StringIO to simulate the file, in your environment read the real file with 'open'.

```
from io import StringIO

sample = 'OutboundManualCall|H|RTYEHLA HTREDFST|Free"flow|Text|20191029|X|X|X|3456\nOutboundManualCall|J|LALALA HTREDFST|FreeHalalText|20191029|X|X|X|3456\nOutboundManualCall|J|LALALA HTREDFST|FrulaalText|20191029|X|X|X|3456\nOutboundManualCall|H|RTYEHLA HTREDFST|Free"flow|Text|20191029|X|X|X|3456'
    
infile = StringIO(sample)
outfile = StringIO()

for line in infile.readlines():
    cols = line.split("|")
    if len(cols) > 9:
        print(f"bad colum {cols[3:5]}")
        line = "|".join(cols[:3]) + "#".join(cols[3:5]) + "|".join(cols[5:])
    outfile.write(line)
print("Corrected file:") 
print(outfile.getvalue())
```

Results in:

```
> bad colum ['Free"flow', 'Text']
> bad colum ['Free"flow', 'Text']
> Corrected file:
> OutboundManualCall|H|RTYEHLA HTREDFSTFree"flow#Text20191029|X|X|X|3456
> OutboundManualCall|J|LALALA HTREDFST|FreeHalalText|20191029|X|X|X|3456
> OutboundManualCall|J|LALALA HTREDFST|FrulaalText|20191029|X|X|X|3456
> OutboundManualCall|H|RTYEHLA HTREDFSTFree"flow#Text20191029|X|X|X|3456
```